# Win32 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: winapi, winsock

I'm currently trying to learn WinSock coding from http://johnnie.jerrata.com/winsocktutorial/ however when I compile my listening socket, I get 9 `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` errors. They all look to be the same function names that are used in the code prefixed with an underscore after the function name it says `referenced in function _WinMain@16`

This also happens when I run the code example that is available for download, so I don't think I've made a mistake.

What is an unresolved external and how do I go about fixing one? I can post the code if needed but it's all visibile on that link. I'm using Visual Studios 2010, Win32 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unresolved external is linker error, telling you that you didn't link symbols you are getting those unresolved externals to into the binary.

Quoting from the site you linked:

> Feel free to download the entire tutorial code listing. Remember that any code presented in this tutorial **should be linked with the Winsock library, usually wsock32.lib or something similarly named**. Also, when using code exactly as presented in the tutorial in your own IDE (Dev-C++, Microsoft VC++, C++ Builder, etc.), choose to build a Windows project with a WinMain() to avoid errors.

One of ways to link it is:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")
```

Also, consider using [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) instead of raw WinSock.

Comment: Nothing worse then loosing your mind over something you could've fixed by being more thorough lol. Thanks for that, I linked wsock32.lib and it worked straight away.